# How to open a new window with keeping mouse focus on the older window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a new windoe on clicking of a image and at the same time keeping my mouse cursor on the current window.
I tried to open a new window using target="_blank" but it brings my cursor over new window
Is there to any way to implement it?

Comment: It's a browser/OS preference and you cannot control it programatically with any cross-browser consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what you call a ["pop-under"](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471241/So-You-Want-A-Pop-Under-Window-Huh.htm) (instead of pop-up)

The main idea is to build the pop-up using `window.open` and intentionally lose it's focus using `blur()`

however, you can't guarantee that it pops under or even over the browser. some browsers have extreme anti pop-up settings, others not so. others open in tabs instead of pop-ups.